# Select Region Then City in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to display custom checkout fields in WooCommerce. Our country is divided into regions. What I want is to choose the region first, then the city.

The code I'm using shows the region dropdown field but doesn't show the city select field:

```php
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_region'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'guria' => 'Guria',
            'adjara' => 'Adjara',
            // Add other regions here
        ),
        'required' => true,
        'label' => __('Region', 'woocommerce')
    );
    
    $fields['billing']['billing_city'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(),
        'required' => true,
        'label' => __('City', 'woocommerce')
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function load_custom_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-js', 'regions_cities', array(
        'guria' => array('City1', 'City2'),
        'adjara' => array('City3', 'City4'),
        // Add other regions and their cities here
    ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_js' );
```

I also use the js code which is in the correct directory. The console log is clean and does not show any errors.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('select#billing_region').change(function() {
        var selectedRegion = $(this).val();
        var cities = regions_cities[selectedRegion];
        var citySelect = $('select#billing_city');
        citySelect.empty();
        $.each(cities, function(index, city) {
            citySelect.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', city).text(city));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('select#billing_region').change(function() {
var selectedRegion = $(this).val();
var cities = regions_cities[selectedRegion];
var citySelect = $('select#billing_city');
citySelect.empty();
$.each(cities, function(index, city) {
citySelect.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', city).text(city));
});
});
});`

Comment: Please add the JS into the question as well, properly formatted - this is hard to read in a comment.

Comment: I already fixed it. thanks

Comment: And what debugging have you done on this so far? Have you verified it enters your change handler in the first place? And if so, what happens next?

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I meant to change the post. I couldn't get the code to work

Comment: _"I couldn't get the code to work"_ - yes, that was already clear. Which is _why_ I asked you, what debugging you have done so far.

Comment: @CBroe  I checked with the WordPress debugger. The console log is clean. Brings all files to the source. Shows the region field but does not show the cities field.  I also checked with chatgpt

Comment: _"I checked with the WordPress debugger"_ - are you simply talking about enabling WP debug mode here? That is for the server-side coding only. You should debug the actual JavaScript portion of this. Set a breakpoint or add a `debugger` statement, and/or make debug outputs using `console.log`

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase  I think its JS problem

Comment: What do you mean by "I think"? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes and missing things in your code… Try the following revised code:

```php
function get_regions(){
    return array(
        'guria' => 'Guria',
        'adjara' => 'Adjara',
        // Add other regions here
    );
}

function get_regions_cities(){
    return array(
        'guria' => array(
            'city1' => 'City 1', 
            'city2' => 'City 2'
        ),
        'adjara' => array(
            'city3' => 'City 3', 
            'city4' => 'City 4'
        ),
    );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'regions_cities_custom_checkout_fields' );
function regions_cities_custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_region'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => get_regions(),
        'required' => true,
        'label' => __('Region', 'woocommerce')
    );
    
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['options'] = array('' => '');
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['required'] = true;

    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_regions_cities_scripts' );
function enqueue_regions_cities_scripts() {
    // Note: for child themes use: get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
    wp_enqueue_script( 'regions-cities-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/regions-cities.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );

    wp_localize_script( 'regions-cities-js', 'wc_params_regions_cities', get_regions_cities() );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your (child) theme or in a plugin.

The JavaScript file `regions-cities.js`:

```js
jQuery( function($){
    if (typeof wc_params_regions_cities === 'undefined')
        return false;

    function setCitiesOptionsForRegion( region ) {
        var cityOptions = wc_params_regions_cities[region],
            citiesField = $('select#billing_city');
    
            citiesField.empty();
        
        $.each(cityOptions, function(slug, name) {
            citiesField.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', slug).text(name));
        });
    }

    setCitiesOptionsForRegion( $('select#billing_region').val() );

    $('select#billing_region').change(function() {
        setCitiesOptionsForRegion( $(this).val() );
    });
 });
```

Tested and works.

Now when checkout loads, the Billing City dropdown field appear, and it's populated with the corresponding cities:

[image]