# Display the region name in WooCommerce admin order pages

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout, orders

Hello I'm using [Select Region Then City in WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830888/select-region-then-city-in-woocommerce-checkout/77831888#77831888) previous answer to one of my questions, to add checkout fields for region and city dropdown fields.

[Select Region Then City in WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830888/select-region-then-city-in-woocommerce-checkout)

And I am displaying the selected region in admin order page with the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'aba_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function aba_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
     $value = $order->get_meta( '_billing_region' );

    if ( ! empty($value) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Region').':</strong> ' . $value . '</p>';
    }
}
```

But it's displaying an array of values and I want to display a text.

Comment: How is this displaying an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you mean that is displaying the selected region **slug**, but I don't get any array when using my [previous answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830888/select-region-then-city-in-woocommerce-checkout/77831888#77831888).

Based on my [previous answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830888/select-region-then-city-in-woocommerce-checkout/77831888#77831888), to display the selected region **name**, you need to replace your code with the following:

```php
// Utility function: Get the billing region name
function get_billing_region_name( $order ) {
    $region_slug = $order->get_meta('_billing_region');
    $all_regions = get_regions(); 
    return $region_slug ? $all_regions[$region_slug] : null;
}

// Display the region in admin edit order pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'aba_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function aba_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
    if ( $region = get_billing_region_name( $order ) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Region').':</strong> ' . $region . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.